# Error while linking nodeJs package

Tags: node.js

I was trying to run npm link on a nodeJs project but it fails on running **nsp check** command at the end, giving the following error:

> (+) Response Error: 408 Request Timeout

How can i fix that ?

Comment: Read https://airbrake.io/blog/http-errors/408-request-timeout

Answer (score 0):

408 Error indicates that the server did not receive a complete request from the client within the server’s allotted timeout period.

Please check your Internet connection and try again.

Comment: could you please clarify which  server does it try to connect to ? does that has some thing to do with my package.json file ?